# How can I convert JavaScript code into one big Java string

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, server-side, quotes

So I have 1000 lines of javascript.  I need to turn it into a Java String so that I can output (via `System.out.println` or whatever).

I'm looking for an ***online tool to escape all the quotes***...     something geared toward my specific need would be nice as I don't want other special characters changed.  Lines like:

```
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
```

need to stay intact.

The situation mandates the JavaScript be put into a String so please no workarounds.

Comment: +1 to counter cowardly drive-by downvoter. It's not an unclear or unhelpful question. It may not be a smart thing to do, but the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link which features [Crockford's implementation of the `quote()` function](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html). Use it to build your own JavaScript converter.

**Edit:** I also [slightly modified the function](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/a243b3e46ddb/quote.js) to output an ascii-safe string by default.

**Edit2:** Just a suggestion: It might be smarter to keep the JavaScript in an external file and read it at runtime instead of hardcoding it...

**Edit3:** And here's a fully-featured solution - just copy to a `.html` file and replace the dummy script:

```
<script src="quote.js"></script>
<script>
// this is the JavaScript to be converted:
var foo = 'bar';
var spam = 'eggs';

function fancyFunction() {
    return 'cool';
}
</script>
<pre><script>
document.writeln(quote(
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].firstChild.nodeValue, true));
</script></pre>
```

Comment: A better version of this script which also escapes quotes: http://jsbin.com/ujumus/11/

Comment: The two links in the answer to not work, but the link of @Yahor still works to see a quote example in `js`. Nevertheless it is worthwhile looking into Mr `Crockford's`.

Comment: @Yahor in the `js bin`, I cannot see in the html where the js quote file is included. And I do not know what the other functions besides `quote` do.

Comment: @Timo a simplified version of the same script https://jsbin.com/qifisaromi

Answer (score 1):

You can compress the file using one of the available tools to achieve this effect:

[YUI Compressor Online](http://yui.2clics.net/)

[Dean Edward's Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

[Douglas Crockford's JSMIN](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant, the question is about escaping quotes in a String not making 1000 lines of JavaScript smaller.

Comment: They make 1000 lines of JavaScript one line of JavaScript.

Comment: @Diodeus: But that's not what Paul wants to do - he's looking for a function which produces appropriate escape sequences for unsafe characters used in scripts...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jsmin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) tool to compress the Javascript to a single line (hopefully), but it doesn't escape the quotes. This can be done with search/replace in an editor or the server side scripting language used.

Comment: the number of lines is relevant, you can have new line characters in a String.

Answer (score 0):

So everything I tried ended up breaking the javascript.   I finally got it to work by doing the following:

Using Notepad++:

1. Hit Shift + Tab a bunch of times to unindent every line
2. Do View -> Show End Of Line
3. Highlight the LF char and do a Replace All to replace with empty string
4. Repeat for the CR char
5. Highlight a " (quote character) and do a Replace All with \" (escaped quote)... just typing the quote character into the Replace prompt only grabbed some of the quotes for some reason.
6. Now You have 1 enormously long line... I ended up having to break the 1 string apart into about 2000 character long lines....   The crazy long line was killing IE and/or breaking the Java String limit.